# accessing relation on object variable changes the variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was comparing objects, and ran across unexpected behavior.
The following code is not how I encountered it, but is the simplest way to explain/reproduce the behavior/error:

```
$obj1 = MyModel::find($id);
$obj2 = MyModel::find($id);
dd($obj1 == $obj2);
```

will of course return **true**.
However, if I use one of the objects to get a collection of related objects (with a simply hasMany in the model), the object seems altered.

```
$users = $obj1->users;
dd($obj1 == $obj2);
```

now returns **false** instead.

Both objects still have the same attributes, so I can simply check the ids, but I do not understand why the objects are not the same anymore, can someone explain to me how and why the object is altered by accessing the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `$obj1->users` loads the `users` Collection into the `Model`'s `relationships` array. This does alter it enough for loose comparison to return `false` Compare `dd($obj1, $obj2)`

```
MyModel {
  ...
  #attributes: array:2[...],
  #original: array:2[...],
  #relations: array:2[...],
  ...
}

MyModel {
  ...
  #attributes: array:2[...],
  #original: array:2[...],
  #relations: array:0[...],
  ...
}
```

This is what your first example looks like. Now, if you use `$users = $model2->users`, it looks like this:

```
MyModel {
  ...
  #attributes: array:2[...],
  #original: array:2[...],
  #relations: array:0[...],
  ...
}

MyModel {
  ...
  #attributes: array:2[...],
  #original: array:2[...],
  #relations: array:1[
    "users" => Collection { ... }
  ],
  ...
}
```

If you want them to be the same, you would have to eager load the relationship as such:

```
$obj1 = MyModel::with(["users"])->find($id);
$obj2 = MyModel::with(["users"])->find($id);
$users = $obj2->users; // With or without this line, the comparison returns `true`
dd($obj1 == $obj2); // true
```

At that point, both `$obj1` and `$obj2` have the same `relations: array:1[]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, great explanation of what happens under the hood.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!

Comment: @MrEvers Since you're comparing two Eloquent models, I thought I'd mention something else. In addition to this (correct) answer, Eloquent models have an `is()` function to determine if two model instances point to the same database record. So, if that is your intention, you could do `$obj1->is($obj2)` (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more related to PHP rather than Laravel. If you have a look at the [Comparing objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) documentation you will see that:

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values (values are compared with ==), and are instances of the same class.

So... In your case you loaded `$obj1` and `$obj2`

```php
$obj1 = MyModel::find($id);
$obj2 = MyModel::find($id);
```

If we follow the guidelines when running the `dd` PHP will look for:

**1. Instance of the same class**

It's **true** => `MyModel::class == MyModel::class`

**2. Attributes**:
It's true as well since same class equals same attributes.

**3. Values**

You looked for the same database `id` so Laravel mapped the query result inside two different instances... but retrieving the same values.

---

Now, when you perform a [lazy load](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading), Laravel will push inside the `relations` array a new value. So the comparison will succed for point 1 and 2, but fails on point 3 since

```php
dd($obj1->relations)

/* RESULT
 * [...]
 * #relations: array:1[
 *  "users" => Collection { ... }
 * ],
 */

dd($obj2->relations)

/* RESULT
 * [...]
 * #relations: array:0[],
 */
```

The values inside this attributes are different, and the comparison fails.

Answer (score 0):

The objets are not the same, because when you run a query like $obj1->users; the $obj1 is altereded, If you dd() the $obj1 you´ll see that the object has a new attribute, call users which is a collection of users in this case.

Now if you try to compare those two objects, you will get false, because they have differents attributes.

Now if you call $obj2->users and compare $obj1 == $obj2 again, you´ll get true.

Answer (score 0):

The relations do not get inherited unless you call them. So, when you call the users in the $obj1 the data for the users gets inherited which makes it not the same as the $obj2.

Still, need more clarification then do this

```
dump($obj1);
dump($obj2);
die();
```

and check in the $obj1 you will find the users data or the users array whereas in the $obj2 you do not find anything as such as they still need to be called in it.